# Limit of $\frac{2^n}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

How can I prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}=0$?

Comment: What do you know about limits? Which techniques do you know? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: We have that $$\frac{2^n}{n!} = 2\prod_{3 \leq i \leq n} \frac{2}{i} \leq 2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-2} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Try with this inequality:

$$\frac{2^n}{n!}\leq \frac{2^n}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4^{n-3}}=\frac{4^3}{6} 4^{-n/2}.$$

Since $4^{-n/2}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: That's also very good.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way by ratio test

$$\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{2^n}=\frac2{n+1}\to 0 <1$$

then the sequence converges to $0$.

Comment: @T.Bongers Sorry but I'm going to not reply anymore to such kind of unfair and OT comments. If you have something against an answer, please use the proper ways. I'm at disposal for discussions in chat. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
Let $u_n=\dfrac{2^n}{n!}$.

Calculate $\;\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}$. What is  its limit? What  can you deduce for $u_n$?

Comment: Same idea than mine! Of course the straightforward way,

Comment: @gimusi: Great minds think together… :o) You seem to have posted while I was typing, and I didn't think of checking whether another answer had been posted in the meantime

Comment: That's absolutely fine! 2 ratio tests never killed anyone :)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{2^n}{n!} &= \frac{2}{1} \frac{2}{2} \frac{2}{3} \cdots \frac{2}{n-1} \frac{2}{n} 
\\ &< 2\cdot 1\cdot 1 \cdot 1\dots 1\cdot \frac{2}{n}
\\ &=  \frac{4}{n} \to 0
\end{align}